# How to fill tetris field

Tags: c#

I create console tetris and I need to create tetris board, but i have no idea why my code doesn't works. I want to do something like 
[that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg4Lp.png)

```
for(int i = 0; i < BOARD.GetLength(0); i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < BOARD.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    BOARD[i, j] = "=";
                }

                else if(i == 14)
                {
                    BOARD[i, j] = "=";
                }

                else
                {
                    BOARD[i, 0] = "|";
                    BOARD[i, 7] = "|";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Show()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < BOARD.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(BOARD[i, j]);
            }

            Console.Write("\n");

        }
    }
```

[Result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2YbO.png)

Comment: It doesn't work because Console doesn't know *where* to write. Try using `Console.SetCursorPosition();` before `Console.Write()`

Comment: Adding lines to your Output in console is always tricky. You can view it as 1 line before (top), one line after (bottom), and one left and 1 right for each row in between. When you want to redraw, Console.Cleat().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for arrey [15,15]:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD.GetLength(0); i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < BOARD.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == 14)
                {
                    BOARD[i, j] = "=";
                }
                else if (j == 0 || j == 14)
                {
                    BOARD[i, j] = "|";
                }
                else
                {
                    BOARD[i, j] = " ";
                }
            }
        }
```